# Material-ui v1 tabs label wrap bug

Tags: tabs, material-ui

Using Material UI @next v1.0.0 beta 32:

---

Tabs labels wrap as expected on smaller devices.

But the wrapping makes them change font-size, which in turn, in some screen width removes the need for the text to wrap.

So I end up with this: tabs with non-wrapped labels and different font sizes.

sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o7worrr32q

In order to see the described result make the window narrow enough for at least 1 tab label to wrap, but not all.

I' have overriddeen the wrapped styles this way:

```
<Tab
  value={value}
  label='my label'
  classes={{
     root: classes.tab,
     rootPrimarySelected: classes.selected,
     labelWrapped: classes.labelWrapped
  }}
/>
```

and my style:

```
 labelWrapped: {
   fontSize: '0.875rem'
 },
```

The problem as illustrated in [this gif animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhOL7.gif), is that as you click on other tabs, the text wraps and unwraps alternatively, seemingly without reason.

My guess is that a padding changes somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Add these styles (`.MuiTab-wrapper-62 { border: 1px solid yellow; } .MuiTab-labelContainer-63 { border: 1px solid red; }`) to end of your css and test it again. After doing it, is the problem show itself to you?

Comment: @RAM, thanks, but no difference. I ended up overriding the width of the tabs using the provided breakpoints from the theme. So the issue still exists, but I worked around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought in the end:

I only had to use the MUI provided css override `labelWrapped`, as documented in [the MUI API](https://material-ui-next.com/api/tab/):

```
<Tab
   aria-label="aria description"
   label="Wrapping Label"
   icon={<Icon />}
   value={x}
   classes={{
      root: classes.root,
      labelContainer: classes.labelContainer,
      rootInheritSelected: classes.rootInheritSelected,
      labelWrapped: classes.labelWrapped,
   }}
   component={Link}
   to={{
     pathname: '/my/router/url',
     search: this.props.location.search,
   }}
/>
```

and my overriding styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    minWidth: 60,
    height: '100%',
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    paddingBottom: 5,
    wordWrap: 'break-word',
    flex: 1,
    overflowWrap: 'break-word',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  labelContainer: {
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
  },

  rootInheritSelected: {
    color: '#FFF',
  },
  labelWrapped: {
    fontSize: '0.875rem',
  },
})
```